# Django 2.0 - Make test worker to run tests in non-app folder

Tags: django, django-tests

In Django 2.0, I have following project structure, which I can't change, no matter what:

```
grocery_store_website
    manage.py
    grocery_store  # contains wsgi, settings,etc.
    app1
    app1
    non-app-utils
        __init__.py
        helpers.py
        serializers.py
        model_mixins.py
        tests
            test_helpers.py  # I want test runner to run these.
```

It turned out, I need to write unit tests for `non-app-utils`. Mentioned directory is not a registered Django App and never will be. These tests must be located in `tests` directory, located in `non-app-utils`.  How can I make Django's test runner to discover and run also tests from `non-app-utils` directory?

If I run Django tests with directly specified path `./manage.py test utils.tests.test_helpers`, it works. However `./manage.py test` does not. Any ideas how to go on?

Comment: did you added `__init__.py` in `non-app-utils` directory ?

Comment: Yes, I updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jerin Peter George suggested adding `__init__.py` file into `non-app-utils` directory. However, problem was, there is `__init__.py` file missing in `non-app-utils/tests` directory!

After I add those and run `./manage.py test`, Django's test runner found my tests and ran them as I needed to!